# Display last uploaded image

Tags: php

I working on an image gallery with the thumbnails and main image on the same page. I have ordered the thumbnails so that the last uploaded image standing on top but I also want that this image is displayed as main image. My site is http://www.robcnossen.nl/view_album.php?album_id=7

I can't find if it can be done with mysql but maybe I am looking right.
I'm trying to find the solution in PHP but all what I find on internet I can't get it working for me.

I thought that array multisort, filectime and ksort would solve my problem but nothing changed.
A part of my code is;

```
print_r ($images);
//$dirname = dirname(__FILE__);
//filectime($dirname);
//ksort($images);
array_multisort($images, SORT_DESC);
if(isset($image['album'], $image['id'], $image['ext']));     
    $foto = 'uploads/' . $image['album'] . '/' . $image['id'] . '.' . $image['ext'].   '';

$standaardwaarde=isset($_GET['image_id']) ? $_GET['image_id'] :$foto;

echo'<img src="' ,htmlentities($standaardwaarde), '" title="" />';
```

How can the last uploaded image be shown as main image?

Answer (score 1):

If the $images is a return variable from a DB query, you can change that query by adding an ORDER BY timestamp (I see on your var_dump that there is a timestamp).

Comment: I changed $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_id`, `image_name`, `album_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id ORDER BY `image_id` DESC"); into $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_id`, `image_name`, `album_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC"); but unfortunately, no change

Answer (score 0):

If you store it in a mysql database and your image are stored with an auto increment field or a date field you can use the ORDER BY clause to get the last image as the first (inverse order):

`ORDER BY id DESC` or `ORDER BY timestamp DESC`.

your main image will be then:

$retrieved_array[0]['field_to_show']

Comment: I changed $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_id`, `image_name`, `album_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id ORDER BY `image_id` DESC"); into $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_id`, `image_name`, `album_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC"); but unfortunately, no change

Comment: how do you retrieve the image that you want to show as main image?  you have posted if(isset($image['album'], $image['id'], $image['ext']));     
    $foto = 'uploads/' . $image['album'] . '/' . $image['id'] . '.' . $image['ext'].   '';
but where do you assign the $image variable?

Comment: That is in an get_image funtion;function get_images($album_id) {
 $album_id = (int)$album_id;

 $images = array();
 
 $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_id`, `image_name`, `album_id`, `timestamp`, `ext` FROM `images` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC");
 while ($images_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query)) {  
  $images[] = array(
  'id' => $images_row['image_id'],
  'img_name' => $images_row['image_name'],
  'album' => $images_row['album_id'],
  'timestamp' => $images_row['timestamp'],
  'ext' => $images_row['ext']
  );
 }
 return $images;
}

Comment: yep but you return an $images array and use an $image array, so you are either using an undefined value or not using it correctly since to address the first image you have to do : $images[0]['image_id']. hope i am clear enough :)

Comment: You mean that I have to use for example $foto($images[0]['image_id']) instead of $foto;? I get an error now(Fatal error: Call to undefined function uploads/7/122.jpg) but do I have to look in this direction?

Comment: try with $foto = 'uploads/' . $images[0]['album'] . '/' . $images[0]['image_id'] . '.' . $images[0]['ext'].   '';

Comment: Thanks kawashita86, I was looking for the wrong solutions, your solution is helping me out here.